# SQL Statement to get contract renewal amount by time range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two views. One view shows me the expiration dates of contracts of a customer. The other one is returning all the start dates of the customer's contracts. I wan't to find out the renewal amount of an expired contract. The rule is, that the customer has to start a contract in 90 days after a contract was expired.

http://d.pr/i/bITI

Pretend that the analysis period is Jan 2013. I have an Expiration Amount of 2835,15. Now I have two (2835, 1596) contract starts in the next 90 days after this expiration.

I need a query to get the result:

http://d.pr/i/3ztY

Tried a lot of statements but I found no way to get this result. Any ides?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry just read, I got it wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer that I've tried

Table One :

```
USE [NMIIFDB_DEV]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tes1]    Script Date: 5/3/2013 4:20:35 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tes1](
    [ContractEndDate] [date] NULL,
    [CustomerNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContractAmount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Table 2

```
USE [NMIIFDB_DEV]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tes2]    Script Date: 5/3/2013 4:20:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tes2](
    [ContractStartDate] [date] NULL,
    [CustomerNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ContractAmount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

SELECT STATEMENT

```
select YEAR(T1.ContractEndDate) AS ExpirationYear, MONTH(T1.ContractEndDate) as ExpirationMonth,

T1.ContractAmount AS ExpirationAmount, SUM(T2.ContractAmount) AS RenewalAmount
from tes1 T1, tes2 T2

where MONTH(T1.ContractEndDate) = 01 AND YEAR(T1.ContractEndDate) = 2013 AND MONTH(T2.ContractStartDate) = 01 AND YEAR(T2.ContractStartDate) = 2013 

GROUP BY YEAR(T1.ContractEndDate), MONTH(T1.ContractEndDate),
T1.ContractAmount
```

You can declare the parameter you want to compare in parentheses

Comment: Thanks.
Changed WHERE Clause to

`WHERE   MONTH(T1.ContractEndDate) = 01
        AND YEAR(T1.ContractEndDate) = 2013
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.ContractEndDate, T2.ContractStartDate) >= 0
        AND DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.ContractEndDate, T2.ContractStartDate) <= 90
        AND T1.CustomerNo = T2.CustomerNo
`
I will test it with more data

Comment: Another problem is, if I have more than on expiration of one customer in one month. I think then I should use MAX(ContractEndDate) to see which contracts we can value as renewals.

Comment: That's true but the expiration contract of each customer should have one valid contract so I mean it depends on your necessary and business role indeed, accept it if you like the answer hehe green accept button to accept this answer